# How to conditionally select items from a pandas Series

Tags: python, list, pandas, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I am using a Pandas Series which consists of lists of numbers, with words as the index:

```
$10             [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
$100                        [0, 0, 0]
$15                               [1]
$19                            [0, 0]
$1?                            [1, 1]
$20                         [0, 1, 1]
$20-$40                           [0]
```

I am trying to write some simple code which creates a new series which only includes items which contain a list of length 'n' or greater.

A bit like list comprehension for series.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using `list`s in `Series` objects, but you can do what you're asking like this:

**EDIT:** Usage

```
# DON'T use `eval` in production I'm just using it for convenience here
In [7]: s = read_clipboard(sep=r'\s{2,}', index_col=0, header=None, squeeze=1).map(eval)

In [8]: s
Out[8]:
0
$10        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
$100                   [0, 0, 0]
$15                          [1]
$19                       [0, 0]
$1?                       [1, 1]
$20                    [0, 1, 1]
$20-$40                      [0]

In [20]: n = 3

In [21]: s.map(len) >= n
Out[21]:
0
$10         True
$100        True
$15        False
$19        False
$1?        False
$20         True
$20-$40    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool

In [22]: s[s.map(len) >= n]
Out[22]:
0
$10     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
$100                [0, 0, 0]
$20                 [0, 1, 1]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

You shouldn't use `list`s in `Series` objects because they are `object` arrays under the hood, as opposed to a homogeneously typed `Series` which can take advantage of the speed of `numpy`.

Comment: thanks! i actually converted it to a series object from a dictionary of lists. why is it better not to use a series? and would the solution be the same with a dictionary of lists?

Comment: It's not that using a `Series` is "bad" it's that when you put arbitrary objects into a `Series` they are much slower than if you had a homogeneously typed `Series`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
s[s.map(len) >= n]
```